# Root MySQL Access denied even after resetting root password

Tags: mysql, root, mysql5

I know there are a ton of threads on similar issues where people can't connect using root and need to reset their password to regain access, but in my case resetting the password is not a problem.  I just can't login, even with the correct password.

I noticed several months ago that I suddenly wasn't able to login as root, but I put that issue aside as I had access via another user account that was sufficient for my needs, at least temporarily, but now I really need to be able to use root.  I'm using Windows Server 2016 and MySQL 5.5.45

This is what I did to try to solve the problem

1. Stop mysql service
2. Restart mysql service with skip-grant-tables enabled
3. On the command line, login as root without the password
4. use mysql;
5. UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('MyNewPassword') WHERE user ='root';
6. flush privileges;

According to the interweb that's supposed to do the trick, and it did appear to work as mysql reported 1 row having been changed.  So I exited mysql and tried to re-login using root and my new password.

I still get **ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)**

I also tried a variation of the above by adding UPDATE user SET plugin=""; and UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password"; just before flush privileges, but that made no difference.

I also tried starting mysql by passing in an init file, [per these instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html), which has in it:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPassword') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

That was actually the first thing I tried but not only did that not work, the command line never came back.  It just hung, so I had to kill it and look for a different solution.

So the question is, if the password is not the problem, what could be causing me to have access denied to the root user?

Comment: In the past, I have found that there are two different ways that MySQL (MariaDB) gets installed.  RedHat and Ubuntu have completely different configurations.  One has user 'root' as it pertains to MySQL, the other uses the system root user to manage root access.  VERY CONFUSING.  Try getting in using sudo instead of relying on the password.. can't hurt to try.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe sudo is a unix only concept.  I'm using Windows Server 2016.

Comment: DOUGH!  I should read better!  Sorry.